How to setup Grafana Heatmap From SQL Query with predefined buckets?
I want to build a Grafana Heatmap for the SQL query bucketing data over 15 minute intervals in two predefined buckets. Table view is fine but heatmap view shows both count and bucket.
The query:
SELECT
    updated,
    CASE 
        WHEN score > 0 AND score < 10 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as bucket,
    COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE $__timeFilter(updated)
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated)/(15 * 60)), bucket


As you can see there's two buckets, grouped by 15 minute interval.
Grafana heatmap table view:
Grafana heatmap table view
How I can visualize count of items in each bucket in Heatmap? Grafana shows this:
Grafana Heatmap

Create anwser - don't use question for answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Of course I missed the tutorial part showing that buckets go in separate columns:
SELECT
    updated,
    SUM(CASE WHEN score > 0 AND score < 10 then 1 else 0 end) AS A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN score >= 10 then 1 else 0 end) AS B
FROM table
WHERE $__timeFilter(updated)
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated)/(15 * 60))

